# Change mouse cursor when hovering over image resize handles in IRichEdit control

Tags: c++, winapi

I have very limited experience in win32 API, so please excuse me if the question is dumb. I have inserted an image in a windowless rich edit control. When selecting the image, the eight resize handles appear on it as expected. However, I do not know how to change the mouse cursor when one of those handles is hovered over.

How can I figure out if a resize handle is being hovered over or not? Does a rich edit control allow that automatically or do I have to do it manually? Doing it manually would be no problem, but I also don't know how to get the position and dimensions of the selected image in a windowless rich edit control.

So to sum it all up, I need either a way to automatically change the mouse pointer when one of the image resize handles is hovered over, or a way to find the position and dimensions of the selected image in a windowless rich edit control. Any help in form of documentation or code snippets would be very helpful!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the control's [`WM_SETCURSOR` message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-setcursor). In response to this message, to change the cursor style, you can use [`LoadCursorFromFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadcursorfromfilea) or [`LoadCursor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadcursorw) to load resources or and [`SetCursor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcursor) to set the cursor.

```
case WM_SETCURSOR:
{
    if (static_cast<HWND>(wParam) == GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_YOURCONTROL))
    {
        SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_HAND));
        SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, DWLP_MSGRESULT, TRUE);
        return TRUE;  
    }
    return FALSE; 
}
```